# Tilt face 45 degree angle

Tags: modeling, faces

Just starting with blender coming from SketchUp
I Tried shear tool to tilt the face at 45 degree but get undesired artifacts

What could be a good approach? maybe a cut out of some sort?

[image: tilt face at 45 deg]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you need the bottom edge to stay vertical, put the 3D cursor at the bottom of your selection and in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel choose *3D Cursor*, then select the part you want to tilt, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in the *Operator* box enter *Offset > -1* so that it tilts 45° (the *Shear* tool moves the selected vertices along the X axis of your view by default):

[image]

The *Shear* tool is available in the *Tool* bar:

[image]

Another solution would be to use the *Knife* tool with an *Angle Snapoing Increment* of 45°, or rotate your object 45° and cut perpendicularly (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut perpendicularly, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

Comment: Wow these solutions are more elegant I think then using a boolean modifier.
Will definitely give your solution a try, many thanks for replying to my question!

Comment: Note you can access the shear tool from the left hand shelf in the 3D viewport, it can be more helpful because it has gizmos associated with it

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know, I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Shear tool did the job for me after some fiddling around, the little screen casts are golden!

Comment: Yes nice idea to put the Shear tool in the tool bar  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Got it using a boolean modifier to cut out the difference.